# Understanding nested for loops

Tags: java

I am very green to Java programming and, in the course I am taking, I 'cheated' on one of the exercises and tried reverse engineering a solution. However, I can't quite understand how the last part works. I tried running through it on paper, trying to work through a solution, but got confused.

The goal was to write 20 numbers from the keyboard and display them in decreasing order. Can someone help me see the execution flow of the `for` loop and the nested `for` loop in the last portion of my code?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/* In decreasing order */
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int[] array = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      array[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    }
    sort(array);
    for (Integer x: array) {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }

  public static void sort(int[] array) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
      for (int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
        if (array[j] < array[k]) {
          int l = array[j];
          array[j] = array[k];
          array[k] = l;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's an implementation of a bubble sort algorithm. It sorts the array. Use the debugger to step through it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "reverse engineer" ... if you didn't understand what you were reversing, then how did you end up writing it correctly?

Answer (score -2):

solution:

Arrays.sort(array);

for(int i=(20-1);i>=0;i--){

System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

}`

System.out.println();

---

20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: @CobaltGecko How will OP understand what's going on when the "simpler" solution is a black box? `Arrays.sort()` completely obscures all implementation details -- there isn't a clue as to what's going under the covers.